# How to read file from ear/war/jar?

Tags: java, file, jax-rs, war, ear

I have EAR which contains another WAR. The project structure is shown below:

```
project.ear
 |-- lib
 |-- META-INF
 |-- project-web.war
 |    |-- META-INF
 |    |-- WEB-INF
 |    |    |-- classes
 |    |    |    `-- com
 |    |    |         `-- example
 |    |    |              `-- services
 |    |    |                   `-- ListPageService.class
 |    |    |-- lib
 |    |    |-- web.xml
 |    |    `-- weblogic.xml
 |    `-- content.html
 `-- project-services.jar
```

In the WAR, there's a JAX-RS class `ListPageService` which needs to read the `content.html` file. How do I access that file?

Comment: Your tree is not correct; the class file should be in content.war/WEB-INF/classes. So where in your war file is the content.html -exactly-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to get at resources in a WAR file is via `ServletContext.getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`.  You should be able to get access to the `ServletContext` in a JAX-RS class by declaring a field annotated with `javax.ws.rs.core.Context`

```
@Context ServletContext servletContext;
```

then in the request handling method you can say

```
URL content = servletContext.getResource("/content.html");
// alternatively
// InputStream content = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/content.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this answer is no longer applicable to the question as it is formulated now. The suggested method works only to get resources from the classpath.

Have a look at the `Class.getResourceAsStream` method. It allows you to access files found in the class path.

Comment: Thanks, but I faced next issue: if I run getClass().getResourceAsStream("."), the absolute path is C:\Oracle\middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\tmp\_WL_user\project-ear\7epkmz\war\WEB-INF\lib\_wl_cls_gen.jar . This jar contains only *.class files, without static content from original WAR. Any thoughts?

Comment: The name you specify is relative to the location of the class. This can be overridden when the name starts with /. To get the file in your example use "/content.html"

Comment: Web content resources are not covered by the classpath at all. It's totally beyond me why this answer got 4 upvotes already.

Comment: Thats because the question has been edited in the meantime, the resource was in the classpath before.